# youtube embed - fullscreen button does not work

Tags: youtube, embed, fullscreen

recently I discovered issues with embedded youtube videos on my site - the fullscreen-button does not work anymore. It sure did once. The button is visible, but when clicked, nothing happens.

I'm using the Youtube Javascript API to embed videos in my website, much like this example by Google http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=youtube#simple_embed

I use the fs=1-Parameter to enable the Fullscreen-Button.
If you wanna try this out, just append it to the URL-Parameters in the example and hit "Run Code". It even doesn't seem to work in the Google Code Playground! Is this a general problem or might there be some workaround? I tried this in Chrome, FF and Opera, it's all the same.

My site http://trashnet.de/youloop/?id=HCdkYRx63HM

Best regards :)

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Did you ever figure out what was causing it?

Answer (score 6):

Ah, figured it out: you need to set `allowFullScreen` to `'true'`.